# Javascript remove value from var that is unique

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found some other similar questions that I tried to work from but my problem seems to be slightly different.

I need to remove the options/values from a var of names based on other inputs, however I am having trouble removing the certain options/values because they are not actually the same.

Because of the way data is imported into the code (can't change this right now), additional numbers and text may be added to the end of the names in getRandomName5(). I need the code to recognize RED and RED1 as the same, and find a unique value for input_5 that does not match the values of the other inputs.

I can get it working if getRandomName5() contains equal values as the others, but not similar.

Can I set RED and RED1 as one value so that they will be seen as equal?

Thanks for the help

EDIT - Ill try to be more specific.

I am filling in an HTML table and lines of code that are the "names". So because the codes/names are listed with numbers, they are not exactly the same.

For example:
I would like these two randomly selected lines of code to be recognized as the same.

```
<td>1</td><td>JIM</td><td>JOHNSON</td>
<td>5</td><td>JIM</td><td>JOHNSON</td>
```

```js
function getRandomName1() {
  var names = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName2() {
  var names = ['BLACK', 'WHITE', 'GRAY'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName3() {
  var names = ['GOLD', 'SILVER', 'BRONZE'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName4() {
  var names = ['MAGENTA', 'CYAN', 'YELLOW'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName5() {
  var names = ['RED1', 'GREEN1', 'BLUE1', 'BLACK1', 'WHITE1', 'GRAY1', 'GOLD1', 'SILVER1', 'BRONZE1', 'MAGENTA1', 'CYAN1', 'YELLOW1'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];

}


function myFunction1() {
  if (document.getElementById("input_A").value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("input_1").value = (getRandomName1());
    document.getElementById("input_2").value = (getRandomName2());
    document.getElementById("input_3").value = (getRandomName3());
    document.getElementById("input_4").value = (getRandomName4());
    document.getElementById("input_5").value = (getRandomName5());
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction1()">
  <select id="input_A">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
  </select><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_2"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_3"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_4"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_5">
</body>
```

Comment: So you are saying, you can not change the actual code of `getRandomName5`? Then you can not change anything about the local variable contained inside that function either; then your only option probably is to keep on calling that function, until you get a value that is not contained in any of the other input fields already.

Comment: How complex it will be depends on what your criteria are for similar. You need to determine that.

Comment: maye use `str.match()`

Comment: I can change the code, I can't change the names that are imported into the code. @AluanHaddad I can't create lists of names that I consider similar? There isn't a criteria that would work, its just how I group them

Comment: Or wait, `getRandomName5` contains the values from _all_ the other functions (just with the added `1` each time), is that always a given – no more, no less? Then you could also call each of these functions to draw a random value from them, put those four values into an array, and then pick one of those randomly again. But then you would still have to make sure that your four initial draws are “unique”, and have no picked a value you already inserted into one of the other input fields …

Comment: _“I can change the code, I can't change the names that are imported into the code.”_ - please be specific here, which parts exactly _can_ you change, and which part of it is the actual “import” that you can not modify?

Comment: @CBroe The only difference is 2 digits between what's in 5 and the others. The first four will always be unique to each other, as there are no names in more than one list. The last name needs to be different than the first four.

Comment: Why are you creating the same function 5 times? cant you just create a `getRandomName` function and pass the names as a parameter?

Comment: @Reyno Four separate lists? I am here because I need help. If I knew everything I wouldn't be asking

Comment: @Reyno Thanks for the help

Comment: No i mean you can reuse the same function by passing the names to them. I've created [a snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/mc6p1ht3/) to show you

Comment: @REyno Thanks, Ill try to condense it like that

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is iterate through your pervious inputs and remove from that names array in the function any which contain the value `(color)` and `(color)+"1"`. You can also do `!arrayItem.includes(color)` if your looking to be more general

```js
function getRandomName1() {
  var names = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName2() {
  var names = ['BLACK', 'WHITE', 'GRAY'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName3() {
  var names = ['GOLD', 'SILVER', 'BRONZE'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName4() {
  var names = ['MAGENTA', 'CYAN', 'YELLOW'];

  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

function getRandomName5() {
  var names = ['RED1', 'GREEN1', 'BLUE1', 'BLACK1', 'WHITE1', 'GRAY1', 'GOLD1', 'SILVER1', 'BRONZE1', 'MAGENTA1', 'CYAN1', 'YELLOW1'];
  
  // Go though the input_1 to input_4 elements and get their value
  for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    color = document.getElementById("input_" + i).value
    // Go through our names array, if it contains that color or it with a
    // 1 at the end then remove it from names
    names = names.filter(c => c !== color + "1" && c !== color)
  }

  // Now with the colors removed this is be unquie compared to the last inputs
  return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];

}


function myFunction1() {
  if (document.getElementById("input_A").value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("input_1").value = (getRandomName1());
    document.getElementById("input_2").value = (getRandomName2());
    document.getElementById("input_3").value = (getRandomName3());
    document.getElementById("input_4").value = (getRandomName4());
    document.getElementById("input_5").value = (getRandomName5());
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction1()">
  <select id="input_A">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
  </select><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_2"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_3"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_4"><br>
  <input type="text" id="input_5">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks good and Ill try to get it to work with what I need. I should have been more direct with my issue but I was trying to not post a lot of code

Comment: @JimB No problem, if this answers your question you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark to the left of it. Although your original question seemed clear enough to me and this isn't too much code for a question.

Comment: I guess the issue I am having now is that there are extra digits on the first 4 colors too, so I think I need to remove those digits using a similar code that is in 5?

Comment: @JimB You can do `color = color.replace(/\d+$/g, "")` to remove all extra numbers at the end of a string so the digits at the end will be removed and it will just get the color name.

Comment: I couldn't get the replace to work. Its all close, filtering out the different/unique parts of each list of names should work as they would then match